# Can't connect over internet but port is open

Tags: internet, port, remote-control

I trying to connect to my own computer over internet over port 3389, when i go to site [yougetsignal](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) can see that on my external ip  port is open for sure. Also on firewall options Remote Assitance is allowed to connect on it from Public & Private network, and on properties is Allowed connection from internet. The router is set that port forward to my local ip. I can connect from local network to local ip address but when using external ip can not, why?

Can it be that router have some special security rules that restrict incoming connection, or something like that, cause I used too much time same method that work fine, but now don't.

Win 7

Comment: What router are you using?

Comment: the router is Enkom A1521-I

Comment: Can you `telnet` to that 3389 port? If so, there could be some packet corruption. You may need to use protocol analysers to be sure.

Comment: Do you have anything inbetween the router and your internet connection - a DSL or cable modem/router for example? If so, what model is it?

Comment: @leanne between the Enkom router i have only cabel (computer is connected directly to router)

Comment: @billc.cn i can't connect to 3389 from telnet

Comment: What is the Private IP of the computer you want to RDP into? When you forward a port to that IP are you forwarding UDP, TCP, or ANY? Is your Virus protection blocking it, even if you are allowing RDP in the Windows Firewall?

Comment: @j_bombay yes the private is computer that i want connect to (in this case i just want to connect to my computer) use ANY, i don't have any virus protection and any firewall protection, also i turn off windows firewall but still don't work

Comment: If you can try using `nmap -v -PN -p 3389 youripaddress` http://nmap.org/ from another internet connection or use same command from this website http://nmap.online-domain-tools.com/. Post results.

Comment: @week Not shown: 98 filtered ports
PORT STATE SERVICE
3389/tcp open ms-wbt-server  (what mean that 3389 is open)

Comment: And now you are trying to connect from lan by connecting to your public ip? Or you are using another internet connection?

Comment: Don't do that ever.. Don't post your ip address.. Yes, it looks like it's working..

Comment: @week did you try? is it work? it's not problem by ip i can change it anytime?

Comment: It's working. Tried to connect via putty.exe and then with mstsc.exe, examine your logs in `compmgmt.msc`.. there should be record for unsuccessful login..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6425/discussion-between-tonni-and-week)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can it be that router have some special security rules that restrict incoming connection, or something like that, cause I used too much time same method that work fine, but now don't.*

Yes.  I had the same issue with a new ARRIS router/cable modem combo from time warner.  Using the same settings I have always used, the port forwarding 'worked' - but not if I tried to use the external address from an internal computer.

After much research, I traded it in for a slightly older Motorola surfboard, and it works as expected.

Two possible options if getting a new router isn't available - but these probably won't work well for multiple internal computers (especially if different ports get forwarded to different computers): on linux, use iptables to specify the specific usecase of that ip address as a local address. on windows, set up the computer to use a static ip the same as the external ip, as well as an internal ip.

Comment: thnx for effort with little later ... the problem was trivial i have to restart route five times to make them work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to enable port forwarding on your router. When you connect from the internet, you're connecting to your router, it doesn't know to forward traffic on port 3389 to your computer unless you tell it to.

For specifics on how do do this with your router, check [this port forwarding guide](http://portforward.com/routers.htm), which has a large database of instructions for various routers. Generally you'll need to tell the router to forward port 3389 on the external IP to port 3389 at the IP of your computer (you'll probably want to set up a statically assigned IP for your computer as well).

Comment: thnx for answare but i did that and one thing that should be mentioned is that you have to tell port router where to forward port at internal ip cause you are connecting on external ip which than translate that port to your local ip address (your local computer)